# How to get cancancan list of abilites for current_user?

Tags: ruby, cancan, cancancan

How can I get all the abilities for current_user with cancancan in a Rails application ? I've seen this topic https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/pull/221, but who knows would be merger or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's merged for now, so we can use permission[:can] or permission[:can_not]